# Access an Iframe variable from parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a webpage at url `https://parent.com` and it has an iframe injected into it with source `https://iframe.com`. Iframe has a global variable defined called `iframe_variable`. I want to access the `iframe_variable` from `parent` document.

I know browsers don't allow cross origin communication and they provide a `postMessage` API to do it securely.

**Constraint**: I do not have access to any of `parent` or `iframe` code.

On Browser console, I somehow want to access `iframe_variable`

I have tried the following:

1. Get reference of iframe first.

   `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; // There is only one iframe on document`
2. Create a listener for `message` event posted from `parent` window.

   `var iframeListener = function(e) {
       console.log("Got message from parent"); 
       e.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'IFRAME_VARIABLE': window.IFRAME_VARIABLE}));
   }`
3. Create a listener for parent window to accept 'message' posted from iframe.

   `parentListener = function(e) { 
       console.log('Got message from iframe');
       var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
       window.VARIABLE = data.IFRAME_VARIABLE; 
   }`
4. Attach `parent_listener` to `message` event.

   `window.addEventListener('message', parentListener, false);`

Now if i try to post a message to `iframe` from `parent` as follows:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('test message', '*')
```

It doesn't trigger 'iframeListener'. The reason is because it is not registered against the `message` event in iframe.

I don't think I can even do that from the browser console when I am on `parent.com` as any attempt to do `iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener` will result in an error as it will be an attempt to access a different domain.

Is there a workaround that? Is there anything that I am missing in my understanding and research.

P.S: I have not written the origin checks for simplicity. I know I must check for the origin a message is posted from. Not doing that leaves a huge security hole.

Comment: _“Is there a workaround that?”_ - if there was, then the same origin policy would be broken. postMessage would be the way to go here, if you _had_ access to the code, or could get the remote party to implement it. If not - then not possible, because it _must not_ be to begin with.

Comment: ohhhhh, I am myself contradicting my statements. If there is a workaround, it will break the same origin policy. YES.. @CBroe Thanks